# ffil with a group by and matching a condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am willing to foward fill the value of `log` for each id whenever you find the first 1 in the `log` column

Example:

```
df 

id   log
 1     0
 1     1
 1     0
 1     0
 2     1
 2     0
 3     1
 3     0
 3     1
```

to

```
id   log  ffil_log
 1     0         0
 1     1         1
 1     0         1
 1     0         1
 2     1         1
 2     0         1
 3     1         1
 3     0         1
 3     1         1
```

My try was:

```
df['ffil_log']=df.log.where(df.log==1).groupby(df.id).ffill()
```

Comment: does the `log` column contain only 0 and 1 entries?  Why do you need to use `groupby` when the file is already grouped on that column?

Comment: column log only has 1 and 0

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cummax` and `groupby` such as:

```
df['ffil_log'] = df.groupby('id')['log'].cummax()
```

for each id, once your reach 1 in a row, it will be the value for the one after, and you get as expected

```
   id  log  ffil_log
0   1    0         0
1   1    1         1
2   1    0         1
3   1    0         1
4   2    1         1
5   2    0         1
6   3    1         1
7   3    0         1
8   3    1         1
```